# RSA decryption using Public Key - No such Provider

Tags: java, encryption, rsa

I have known public key and encrypted data. I want to decrypt it with public key. My code is look like:-

```
String s = "176byteofhexstring";
BigInteger Modulus = new BigInteger(s, 16);
String y = "03";
BigInteger Exponent = new BigInteger(y, 16);

RSAPublicKeySpec receiverPublicKeySpec = new RSAPublicKeySpec(Modulus, Exponent);
KeyFactory keyFactory = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA");
RSAPublicKey receiverPublicKey = (RSAPublicKey)
    keyFactory.generatePublic(receiverPublicKeySpec);
Cipher rsaCipher = Cipher.getInstance("RSA/NONE/NoPadding","BC");
rsaCipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, receiverPublicKey);
byte[] z = { 176 byte of cipher data };
byte[] m = rsaCipher.doFinal(z);
```

When I am run this code, getting error like:`java.security.NoSuchProviderException: No such provider: BC`.

Could anybody tell me how to avoid this error.

Comment: Are you using BouncyCastle?

Comment: Actually i am not regular with java language and just using Netbeans IDE 8.0. With Study i knew BC is for BouncyCastle , but nothing more i can tell here. Could you advise something here that enhance my knowledge and solve this issue.

Comment: You obviously haven't installed it properly, so the provider isn't found. Reading the documentation should fix that for you.

Answer (score 1):

Add somewhere in the beginning of your code:

```
Security.addProvider(new BouncyCastleProvider());
```

This will register BouncyCastle provider to the JCA.

Another option is to use provider directly:

```
private static final Provider BC_PROVIDER = new BouncyCastleProvider();

...

Cipher rsaCipher = Cipher.getInstance("RSA/NONE/NoPadding", BC_PROVIDER);
```

Comment: thanks for the suggestion, i was initially tried this but i was not .jar with me so getting error in this line, after downloading the jar same line worked.

Answer (score 1):

Just use `Cipher rsaCipher = Cipher.getInstance("RSA/ECB/NoPadding");`. You don't need the Bouncy Castle provider to do textbook RSA. ECB here is a bit of a misnomer that is required for the provider of the standard JRE from Oracle; it's functionality the same as specifying `NONE`.

---

Note that using textbook RSA is [completely insecure](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/20085/1172).

---

Completely missed it initially, but decryption with a public key is not the same thing as signature verification. Use the `Signature` class instead.

Comment: testbook RSA? you mean , not using Any padding makes it insecure??

Comment: Actually i have a certificate and public key of same length so i thought no padding is require in our case.

Comment: For RSA, padding is always required, it's part of the security of RSA. Imagine raising the value 1 to a high power. But other than that, you seem to be in need for the `Signature` class, not the `Cipher` class. Signature generation/verification uses other *concepts* than encryption/decryption.

Answer (score 0):

Here Want to share My doings for others.

Step1 - I was missing .Jar related to BouncyCastle (BC) , here the site help me to download the .jar file - http://www.itcsolutions.eu/2011/08/22/how-to-use-bouncy-castle-cryptographic-api-in-netbeans-or-eclipse-for-java-jse-projects/

step 2 - I download the jar from http://www.bouncycastle.org/latest_releases.html with name - bcprov-jdk15on-152.jar

step 3 - Add this jar to project, Properties -> Library -> Add Jar/folder

step 4 -  add

```
import org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.BouncyCastleProvider;
```

step 5 - add line to your code

```
 Security.addProvider(new BouncyCastleProvider());
```

and it solve my purpose...

Comment: You should use `Security.addProvider()` before any attempt to use any of Bouncy Castle provider security functionality like `Signature.getInstance()`, `MessageDigest.getInstance()`, `Cipher.getInstance()` etc. Also note that there is no way remove or replace provider after `Security.addProvider()` call.

Answer (score 0):

Cipher.getInstance also accepts just the transformation - the provider is optional.  When you don't specify the provider, it will use the default provider as specified in your java.security file.

I came across this while experiencing the same problem (only with the Signature.getInstance), and the answers already provided were very helpful in helping me realize this.